# Which dependencies add in pom.xml file for Jersey 2.x

Tags: rest, jersey, openshift, pom.xml

In my web application I'm using Jersey. I add these dependencies in my `pom.xml` file and all works fine (I've followed this  [guide](https://github.com/shekhargulati/jersey-openshift-quickstart)):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But now I want to add `Jersey 2.x` version in my application, I've replaces these lines with these:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
```

But application doesn't work, I got this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:331)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:392)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
>     org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I'm using `OpenShift` for hosting my app `qith JBoss Application Server 7`.
PS: I'm using `Netbeans IDE` with `OpenShift Plugin`.

Comment: JBoss 7 Uses JAX-RS 1.x, and is probably loading those jars to the classpath. You need to disable JAX-RS on the JBoss instance. You can probably do so in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file. Not sure exactly how, but I'm sure the information is somewhere out there

Comment: You have right, JBoss Application Server 7 have issues with Jersey 2.x versions. Now I am using a simple tomcat server and all works fine, the simplest workaround for me. Thanks.